# C# - Queue Management that that always run and Dequeing

Tags: c#, queue

I need to build a process that listen in WCF for new tasks. (Async)
Every Task get Enqueue'ed (somehow).

What is the Best (Logical and Performance) way to loop the queue and Dequeue it.

I thought about:

```
while(true){
   queue.Dequeue();
}
```

I assume that there are better ways to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace - there is thread-safe queue implementation viz. [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) - although, I suspect that your needs would be better served by [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).

Blocking collection is essentially a thread-safe collection useful for producer-consumer scenario. In your case, WCF calls will act as producers that will add to the collection while the worker thread will act as consumer who would essentially take queued tasks from the collection. By using single consumer (and collection), you can ensure order of execution. If that's not important then you may able to use multiple consumer threads. (There are also `AddAny` and `TakeAny` static overloads that will allow you to use multiple collections (multiple queues) if that is the need.)

The advantage over `while(true)` approach would be avoidance of tight loop that will just consume CPU cycles. Apart from having thread-safe, this would also solve issue of synchronization between queuing and de-queuing threads.

**EDIT**:

Blocking Collection is really very simple to use. See below simple example - add task will invoked from say your WCF methods to queue up tasks while `StartConsumer` will be called during service start-up.

```
public class MyTask { ... }

private BlockingCollection<MyTask> _tasks = new BlockingCollection<MyTask>();

private void AddTask(MyTask task)
{
  _tasks.Add(task);
}

private void StartConsumer()
{
   // I have used a task API but you can very well launch a new thread instead of task
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
        while (!_tasks.IsCompleted)
        {
            var task = _tasks.Take();
            ProcessTask(task);
        }
     });
}
```

While stopping service, one need to invoke `_tasks.CompleteAdding` so that consumer thread will break.

Find more examples on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997306.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460690.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460684.aspx

Comment: Thank you, Please explain... `"while StartConsumer will be called during service start-up"` How do I call StartConsumer, Where do I put it?

Comment: @SexyMF, I was assuming that u r packaging WCF services as windows service. Essentially, u need start consumer thread once at the start-up which will then wait for tasks to be added so that it can process them!

Comment: So what you are saying that _tasks should be public static? so ill be able to access it from global asax?

Comment: @SexyMF - yes - it would be a static member (no need to make it public - rather make methods such as `AddTask`, `StartConsumer` public static.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me, one question, when I am invoking, I don't see in threads window a new thread line, why is that? Isnt that suppose to be performed in a single thread?

Comment: @SexyMF, `Task` API uses thread-pool underneath. So probably, one of the worker thread from the pool would get consumed - however, I am not 100% sure if you would see corresponding physical thread in threads window if the worker (logical) thread is waiting on for task.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have Odesk account?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the infinite loop, I would use events to synchronize the queue. Whenever the WCF call is made, add an element to the queue and send out a "AnElementHasBeenAddedEvent".

The Thread executing the queued tasks listens for that event and whenever it receives it, the queue will be emptied.

Make sure there is only one thread that does this job!

Advantages over the while(true) concept: You do not have a thread that constantly loops through the endless loop and thus eats resources. You only do as much work as needed.

Comment: I agree with that. In addition: Use the `Synchronized` method of the queue as a queue is not thread safe: `Queue.Synchronized(queue).Dequeue()`